# Unityで2Dキャラクタをクリックした場所へ移動、対応したSpriteを表示させるには？

Tags: unity3d

どうも、皆様お世話になっております。

下記の仕様を実現させるために、仕様2の箇所を下のコードで実装してみたのですが、
仕様3の「移動方向に合わせて」の箇所で実装方法に詰まってしまいました。

【仕様】

1. 2Dキャラクタで八方向のSpriteを持つ
2. マウスクリック（またはタップ）でクリックした場所にキャラクタが移動する
3. 移動方向に合わせてSpriteを切り替える

【実装コード】

```
//移動速度
public float speed = 2;

Vector2 vec;

void Update () {
    //移動処理
    if(Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)){
        vec=Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
        //Debug.Log("x="+vec.x+" y="+vec.y);
    }
    transform.position = Vector2.MoveTowards(transform.position, new Vector2(vec.x,vec.y), speed * Time.deltaTime);

}
```

こちらに関して良いアイディアは御座いませんでしょうか？お知恵を拝借したく存じます。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

必要になるのはVector2の演算とMecanimをつかったアニメーションの切り替えです。

どちらも公式のチュートリアルに出てきますので確認してみてください。

- http://japan.unity3d.com/developer/document/tutorial/2d-shooting-game/game/02.html

2つのVector2を引き算した値を取得したXとYのそれぞれが一定の値以上か以下かの組み合わせで8方向の判定を得られます。参考までに4方向の例を挙げます。チュートリアルのようにnormalizeするのもよいでしょう。

```
//移動速度
public float speed = 2;

Vector2 vec;

void Update () {
    //移動処理
    if(Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)){
        Vector2 vec = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
        Vector2 diff = (Vector2) this.transform.position - vec;
        Debug.Log ("x="+diff.x+" y="+diff.y);

        var direction = "nutral";

        if (diff.x > 0 && diff.y < 0) {
            // left up
        } else if (diff.x > 0 && diff.y > 0) {
            // left down
        } else if (diff.x < 0 && diff.y < 0) {
            // right up
        } else if (diff.x < 0 && diff.y > 0) {
            // right down
        }
    }
}
```

- http://japan.unity3d.com/developer/document/tutorial/2d-shooting-game/game/11.html

判定した結果を元にAnimatorControllerにフラグをあてて対応するアニメーションステートに切り替えてはどうでしょうか。サンプルではSetTriggerを使っていますが、SetParameterを使って値を渡すこともできます。

パラメータの場合であればVector2の差分のXとYをそのまま渡し、方向の制御はすべてMecanimのステート制御にまかせてしまうとコードが要らなくなりますね。

Mecanimについては、まさにそのものという記事がありました。

- http://mobiletou.ch/2014/01/unity4-3-%E3%81%A7%E8%BF%BD%E5%8A%A0%E3%81%95%E3%82%8C%E3%81%9F-sprite-%E6%A9%9F%E8%83%BD%E3%82%92%E4%BD%BF%E3%81%A3%E3%81%A6%E3%81%BF%E3%82%88%E3%81%86-%E3%81%9D%E3%81%AE2